# error on connecting to the server : socket io is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i know there's been couple of question about the same problem , i've already check them .

i have very simple node.js chat app

i have a server running on 8000 port and it works fine

my client pages are html , they are running on apache and i'm using socket.io to connect them to the server and it works fine on the local host

but when i upload the app on the server i keep on getting this error in the firebug

```
io is not defined
var socket = io.connect('http://atenak.com:8000/');
```

or sometimes it doesn't show that but when i try to broadcast message from cliend i get this error :

```
socket is undefined
socket.emit('msg', { data: msg , user:'max' });
```

the only difference is i've changed the localhost with atenak.com !

here is my html code

```
var socket = io.connect('http://atenak.com:8000/');
    var user = 'jack';
  socket.on('newmsg', function (data) {
       if(data.user == user )
       {
           $('#container').html(data.data);
       }
  });

     function brodcast(){
           var msg = $('#fild').val();
          socket.emit('msg', { data: msg , user:'max' });
      }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">  </div>
   <input id="fild"  type="text">  <input name="" type="button" onClick="brodcast();">

</body>
```

i have included the sockt.io.js

```
src="http://atenak.com:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"
```

and server is running ok which means socket.io is installed on the server

here is the live page

```
http://atenak.com/client.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting:

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined client.html:7
x GET http://atenak.com:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

indicating that your page cannot load `http://atenak.com:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js`; indeed, if you try to load that URL in the browser, you get a connection error. Make sure that your Node.js server (running Socket.IO) is accessible (e.g. ports not being blocked by a firewall, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Seems port 8000 is not open on your host as per links below

[Reverse ip check for atenak.com](http://www.domaintools.com/research/reverse-ip/?hostname=46.4.110.26) and [Open port check](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)

Answer (score 1):

Socket.io need a javascript file and this file does not load correctly.

Here is the url: http://atenak.com:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js

In this file is defined the `îo` object.